# User denied permission while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock

Tags: docker

**I am trying to access docker within docker.** Using the [steps mentioned here](https://github.com/huygn/til/issues/10) :

It looks like working I can see all the images and containers from the host using the `root` user or using `sudo`.

I want to access docker using user `admin` without using `sudo`.
I did add my user `admin` into the `docker` group but that didn't help.

```
admin@07288dd81437:~$ sudo usermod -a -G docker admin 
admin@07288dd81437:~$ docker images
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.37/images/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Comment: You need to logout/login after changing the groups for the change to take effect.

Comment: I even exited and reentered the container. That did not help.

Comment: I am suspecting the user mapping between the host and the container.

Answer (score 2):

The list of supplementary group ID's is inherited from parent to child processes.  You need to create a new shell session by adding this group to that list with a combination of the **sg** and **newgrp** commands like this:

```
exec sg docker newgrp $(id -gn)
```

The **sg** command runs the **newgrp** command without changing the current group ID, effectively adding the ***docker*** group to the list of supplementary group ID's.

The reason not to simply run `newgrp docker` is to avoid changing the current group ID to ***docker***.